# How to flatten an array like in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, flatten

I've got an array like this:

`val a = Array(1,Array(1,2))`

wanna get a result like `Array(1,1,2)`

It seems that `a.flatten` doesn't work. I got an error: `No implicit view available from Any => Traversable[U].`

How can I do that?

Comment: So you get `Array[Any]` ... Why? Probably something to check "before".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not familiar with flatMap function then you can do same task using map and flatten functions.

First convert `Array[Any]` to `Array[Array[Int]]` using the map function and pattern match

```
val arr = Array(1, 2, Array(3, 4))
val arrOfArrs = arr.map { element => 
   element match {
     case element:Int=>Array(element)
     case element:Array[Int]=>element
   }
}
```

Sample output of above code will be

```
arrOfArrs: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(1), Array(2), Array(3, 4))
```

Now you can flatten arrOfArrs easily using `flatten` function

```
arrOfArrs.flatten
res3: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flatMap` for that as follows:

```
a.flatMap {
  case x: Int => Array(x)
  case a: Array[Int] => a
}
```